# Como ignorar links que não se adequem as condições estabelecidas e continuar com a raspagem?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Gostaria de saber como ignorar os links que não se adequem as condições estabelecidas em título, data_hora e texto; deste modo conseguindo continuar a raspagem do site.

O Erro que ocorre quando um link não tem ou não segue as condições:"Error in data.frame(titulo, data_hora, texto) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"

Segue abaixo o script:

```
# iniciar bibliotecas 
library(XML)
library(xlsx)

#url_base <- "http://www.saocarlosagora.com.br/busca/?q=PDT&page=2"

url_base <- "http://www.saocarlosagora.com.br/busca/?q=bolt&page=koxa"

url_base <- gsub("bolt", "PDT", url_base)

links_saocarlos <- c()
for (i in 1:4){
url1 <- gsub("koxa", i, url_base)
pag<- readLines(url1)
pag<- htmlParse(pag)
pag<- xmlRoot(pag)
links <- xpathSApply(pag, "//div[@class='item']/a", xmlGetAttr, name="href")
links <- paste("http://www.saocarlosagora.com.br/", links, sep ="")
links_saocarlos<- c(links_saocarlos, links)

}

dados <- data.frame()
for(links in links_saocarlos){

pag1<- readLines(links)
pag1<- htmlParse(pag1)
pag1<- xmlRoot(pag1)

    titulo <- xpathSApply(pag1, "//div[@class='row-fluid row-margin']/h2",   xmlValue)
    data_hora <- xpathSApply  (pag1, "//div[@class='horarios']", xmlValue)  
    texto <- xpathSApply(pag1, "//div[@id='HOTWordsTxt']/p", xmlValue)


dados <- rbind(dados, data.frame(titulo, data_hora, texto))

}  
agregar <- aggregate(dados$texto,list(dados$titulo,dados$data_hora),paste,collapse=' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso, acho que um `if` já resolve, por exemplo substituindo a linha que coloca no banco de dados por:

```
if (length(titulo) == 1 & length(data_hora == 1) & length(texto) == 1){
    dados <- rbind(dados, data.frame(titulo, data_hora, texto))
}
```

Ou seja, "só adicione esta nova linha se todos os elementos dela existirem".

No entanto, você poderia fazer a sua raspagem de uma forma mais robusta da seguinte forma:

```
library(plyr)

raspar <- failwith(NULL, function(links){
  pag1 <- readLines(links)
  pag1 <- htmlParse(pag1)
  pag1 <- xmlRoot(pag1)

  titulo <- xpathSApply(pag1, "//div[@class='row-fluid row-margin']/h2",   xmlValue)
  data_hora <- xpathSApply(pag1, "//div[@class='horarios']", xmlValue)  
  texto <- xpathSApply(pag1, "//div[@id='HOTWordsTxt']/p", xmlValue)

  data.frame(titulo, data_hora, texto)
})

dados <- ldply(links_saocarlos, raspar)
```

A função `failwith` captura erros sem parar a execução. Isso é muito bom quando estamos fazendo webscraping, uma vez que são comuns problemas de conexão, por exemplo, que podem causar erros inesperados no código.

Além disso, usar o `plyr` (função `ldply`) tem algumas vantagens com relação ao seu `for`. A principal delas é que você não cresce o objeto dinamicamente, o que normalmente é muito mais rápido. Outra vantagem, é que você pode usar o argumento `.progress = "text"` e colocar uma barrinha de progresso no seu código :)

```
dados <- ldply(links_saocarlos, raspar, .progress = "text")
```

Comment: Mto obrigado pela ajuda Daniel.